# Comparing German words for different contexts of "commute" to mean traveling to work?

Tags: english-to-german

I am writing an article about commuting. So far the words I have found are more related to the word "commute" in a scientific context:

`pendeln` , `umwandeln`, and `verwandeln`

Which makes me asks if there is not a direct translation for this word into German.

But if I use the word German word `Reise` it seems to indicate more of pleasure travel. But I am wondering if this verb can be used to describe your daily travel to work from your house to your workplace?

Comment: commute (intransitive): pendeln; commute (transitive): umwandeln/verwandeln (= change something into something else).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Pendeln` is the only word to use. The other ones are not related to this content.
A `commuter` translates to [`Pendler`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendler). So `pendeln` is the direct translation, although it can have a different meaning in another content.

Comment: Pendeln literally means "to swing back and forth like a pendulum" (between home and workplace in this case). I don't think there is a word describing one way of the commute, as in "I was on my commute this morning".

Comment: @fzwo I think that's what English 'communiting' is supposed to mean. The alternative to 'commuting' would be 'travelling'.

Comment: Well, I am German. I can guarantee you, that the word `pendeln` is the one [**"used" for that**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pendeln) (see 2.). But also it is that "common" that you [**have it here**](http://www.berlin.de/special/finanzen-und-recht/rechner/2636244-2645897-pendlerpauschale-berechnen.html).

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes a dictionary not providing enough context for resolving the appropriate translation will reveal the correct term when searching for the nominalized form.

For *to commute* this will be *commuting* or *commuter* which will give you:

> **commuting:** das Pendeln, der Pendelverkehr, der Berufsverkehr
>   **commuter:** Pendler, Berufspendler.

So the obvious correct verb for *to commute to work* is **pendeln**

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary gives three meanings for *[to commute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commute)*. The one that we are interested in is the first one, but let us first consider the other two.

- Reduce (a judicial sentence, especially a sentence of death) to another less severe one.

  The German word here is *umwandeln*.
- Mathematics (Of two operations or quantities) have a commutative relation.

  The German word here is *vertauschen*.

The first one:

- Travel some distance between one’s home and place of work on a regular basis.

  The German word is *pendeln*, however that implies going forth and back (*pendeln* is the movement of a pendulum). There is no simple German word which describes a single trip to or from work.

Answer (score 0):

"Reise" sagt man bei längeren Strecken oder wenn man am Zielort übernachtet. Eine Reise kann (aber muss nicht) Vergnügen sein: eine Urlaubsreise oder Geschäftsreise.